# How to close keyboard on slide menu

Tags: android, keyboard, slide

I use with "Action bar Sherlock".
I want when touch on screen and show slide menu "keyboard is closed".
i am so confused for this. 
what should i do?

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method to hide keyboard when you need

```
 public void hideTypingKeyboard() {
        try {
            if(getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

**EDIT:**

```
 public static void hideEditTextKeyboard(InputMethodManager imm, EditText edittext) {
        if (edittext != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Did not work.
Even when the slide menu will appear what value will return ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: when keyboard is opened?via Editext?

Comment: I would like to know when the screen is touched and appears slide menu , 
what return value when open slide menu?

Comment: I don't unsderstand what you are try to say by "what return value when open slide menu?"

Comment: Where should I call this function ?

Comment: when slide menu opens